# Is the congruence $x ^ x \equiv a\pmod p$ always solvable?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and let $a$ belong to $\mathbb Z$. How do I prove that the congruence $x ^ x \equiv a\pmod p$ is solvable?

Comment: This is not correct; $x^x \equiv 2 \pmod3$ has no solution.  (Also, please put the question in the body, not just the title.  I have edited accordingly.)

Comment: @Lspice $x=5$ works, does not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, good point.  I was just checking $0 \le x < p$, but I forgot you can't reduce the exponent modulo $p$.

Comment: x^x ≡ 2(mod3) has a solution for x = -1.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem combined with Fermat's little theorem should give the answer (choose $x$ to be $a$ mod $p$ and $1$ mod $p-1$).

Answer (score 6):

Сhoose $x$ congruent to $a$ modulo $p$ and to $1$ modulo $p-1$, say $x=1+(p-1)(p-a+1)$.

Comment: The formula also works for $a=0$ :)

Comment: We'd probably better be careful saying $x = 0$ for $a = 0$, lest we run into concerns about the meaning of $0^0$.  Maybe better go with @DrorSpeiser's suggestion and take $x = p^2$, or some other non-$0$ multiple of $p$?

Comment: @DrorSpeiser indeed, shorten the post